# To copy a folder to mounted flash

Tags: terminal

I want to copy a folder "doc" to a mounted USB.. How can I do that?
the folder has documents in it
The folder 'doc' is in home..while the mounted flash is in media..the name of the folder is flash

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking how to do it from terminal

```
cp -r ~/doc/ /run/media/$USER/flash
```

`$USER` replaces the name of your user

```
-R, -r, --recursive
       copy directories recursively
```

**Note**: Some OS are using `/media` instead of `/run/media`

The command then would be `cp -r ~/doc/ /media/flash`

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of copying programs on Unix/Linux. Take your pick.

You could use 'cp':

`cp -r ~/doc/ /media/flash/` which would copy all the files from doc directly into /media/flash.

You could use 'rsync':

`rsync -av ~/doc/ /media/flash/` which would do the same as above. Rsync, however, detects changes in files and only copies over when it finds changes.

If you get a permissions denied error, make sure you use 'sudo' before the above commands so you can write to your USB stick.

Comment: Thank you so much